# How can I use a destructor in C++ when an object can be changed in another object

Tags: c++, destructor

The situation is like this.

```
class Class1{
public:
    Class1(int N){
        p = new int [N];
     }
    ~Class1(){
        delete []p;

    }
...
private:
    int *p;
};

class Class2(){
public:
    Class2(){
        int N = somthing;
        A = Class1(N);
          ...
    }
    ...
private:
    Class1 A;
}
```

Basically, Class2 is a complex object that uses Class1 as part of it and will change it.
The problem is that if I do this way, the destructor for Class1 will cause error.

Is there any other solutions to this kinds of problem in C++?

Comment: You mean `Class2() : A(something) {}` ? And your `Class1(N)` makes no sense as-written, though it conceptually constructs, then destroys, an instance of `Class1`.

Comment: Hmmm... I see a `new` and `delete[]` mismatch. Should be `new` and `delete`, or `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: You should be calling `delete p;` or `new int[N];`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the typo. There is no mismatch in the actual code, the problem is that A is changed by other member functions is Class2, therefore, the destructor will cause error. i don't know how to deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you have a class that manages a resource, `Class1`, but it is not safely copyable and assignable. Any copy or assignment will result in more than one instance attempting to delete the same array, since all instances will have pointers pointing to one single array. If your class is intended to own the resource, you need to provide a copy constructor and an assignment operator. This is commonly known as [*the rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting NULL pointer is no-op and safe. Thus, set `Class1::p` as `NULL` before destruction can solve the problem.

Comment: I think this answers the intended question which is basically ownership and validity semantics.

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves the problem. What is needed is to follow the rule of three.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, it addresses the problem better than other answers. At the time I said that the question did not include an assignment to `A`, so the solution would potentially be to assign `p = nullptr` when losing ownership of the buffer, with no need for a custom destructor. Now it's obvious that the type is moveable and not copyable, so it's really all just a mess.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Ah right, there wasn't an assignment before. To be cler, my comment applies to the version with `A = Class1(N);`

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing the array delete operator with the single object new operator.  right now the code new's a single integer, whose value is constructed to be N.  not an array of N integers.  you need to use the array new operator.

```
From:
 p = new int (N); /* allocate int initialized to N */

To:
 p = new int [N]; /* allocate N int's */
```

Answer (score -2):

you may want your class2 write like this:

```
class Class2(){
public:
    Class2(){
        int N = somthing;
        A = new Class1(N);
      ...
    }
    ~Class2() {
        if (NULL != A) {
            delete A;
            A = NULL;
         }
    }
   ...
private:
    Class1 *A;
}
```

Comment: There was one problem, now there are two problems: neither `Class1` nor `Class2` are not safely copyable or assignable.

Comment: The destructor of `Class2` is far more elaborate than it needs to be. `delete A;` is sufficient; deleting a null pointer has no effect. Further, setting `A` to `NULL` in the destructor is pointless; the object that holds the pointer is being destroyed, so `A` is going away.